# MEF - Is it possible with directorycatalog to get the latest compiled DLL for the same code?

Tags: mef

Let's say I have a contract

```
public interface IGreeting
{
    string SayHelloWorld();
}
```

And a class in another dll

```
[Export(typeof(IGreeting))]
public class Greeting : IGreeting
{
    public string SayHelloWorld()
    {
        return "GREETING V1";
    }
}
```

I use directorycatalog to get this DLL. I works fine. When I update my source code like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IGreeting))]
public class Greeting : IGreeting
{
    public string SayHelloWorld()
    {
        return "GREETING V2";
    }
}
```

and put this new DLL "Next" to the old Greeting DLL Mef doesnt import multiple different Greeting classes but picks 1 out of 2 DLL and exports 2 times from the same class.

So final executing directory looks like this:

```
MyApp.exe
Greeting_V1.dll   
Greeting_V2.dll
```

I want the application to import 2 Greeting classes with ImportMany. It gives me 2 instances from Greeting_V1.dll. If I delete Greeting_V2.dll it gives me only 1 instance of Greeting_V1.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to me, it looks like you are importing many instances of `IGreeting`, so in that sense, MEF is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  If you want to replace the instance of `Greeting` from the V1 assembly with what is in V2, remove the V1 assembly, that way MEF can only load what is available.

Comment: My problem is that MEF doesn't load V1 and V2 instances but 2 V1 instances. I want it to load 2 different instances. 1 of V1, 1 of V2. I have V1.dll and V2.dll in my folder. I cannot remove V1.dll because the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

It not a MEF problem. The problem is in the loading model of .NET. (or better the way you're objects are loaded by .net)

When MEF loads it returns the correct objects. But when looking for class Greeting when V2 is loaded there is already a Greeting class for V1 dll loaded with the correct class Greeting  name for V2 is referring to. And the loader the dll actually referenced by V2 is not loaded.